# F# - Reverse Pipeline order

Tags: f#

How come that I can do:

```
let printTeams x : unit = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    Seq.toList x |> List.sortBy (fun x -> rnd.Next()) |> printTeams'
```

but not:

```
let printTeams x : unit = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    printTeamsRec'  <| Seq.toList x <| List.sortBy(fun x -> rnd.Next())
```

I'm just getting an error on the last one, which says:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     string
>   list -> 'a -> 'b     but given a
>   string list -> unit     The type ''a
>   -> 'b' does not match the type 'unit'

The error occures on the third line at `printTeamsRec'`

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Is it valid in F# to use a projection which returns different values for the same element if called more than once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things: the translation of the forward pipe to backwards pipe is incorrect, and precedence is different.

```
let printTeams x : unit = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    printTeamsRec' <| (List.sortBy(fun x -> rnd.Next()) <| Seq.toList x)
```

Comment: I guess I thought that I couldnt first sort a list that didnt exist yet, and therefore made the translation quite different.. but yea your'e correct. - Thanks!

Comment: The backwards pipeline is nice if you want to omit the parentheses, but when you have more than one step you should always use the forward pipeline (which is also more logical).

    List.sortBy(fun x -> rnd.Next())
    |> Seq.toList x
    |> printTeamsRec'

Comment: @ebb - you're welcome! The expression `List.sortBy(fun x-> rnd.Next())` is a partially applied function, so the sort is not performed until the backwards pipe operator applies the value of the expression `Seq.toList x`.